# Search for an object list

Tags: c#, list, class, object

I have a class like this.

```
       class man    
      {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string mail { get; set; }
       }
```

I have a list like this

```
List<man> ppl = new List<man>();
```

I want to search for a man with name "Nimal" in the list and delete that man. How to do that?

Comment: What happens if there is more than one man named "Nimal"? Should all "Nimal"s be deleted? The first? The last? Should you go to a second criterion at that point?

Answer (score 2):

How about [List.RemoveAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the
>   specified predicate.

```
arts.RemoveAll(x => x.name == "Nimal");
```

Comment: Slightly different from the request, since this deletes all occurrences but the OP says to delete "a" (i.e. presumably the first) ;)

Comment: @astander
Thanks how to do with a if condition?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete the first found in list:

```
if(arts.Any(x => x.name == "Nimal"))
{
arts.Remove(arts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "Nimal"));
}
```

if you want to delete all entries with matching condition then,you can do this way:

```
if(arts.Any(x => x.name == "Nimal"))
{
arts.RemoveAll(x => x.name == "Nimal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Filtered= ppl.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Nimal");
var finalresult= ppl.Except(Filtered).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you a want the first occurrence of the name otherwise checkout @astander answer:

```
 var firstMatch = ppl.First (p => p.Name == "Nimal");
 ppl.Remove (firstMatch);
```

If you prefer `for` loop and `if-condition` you can do something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ppl.Count; i++)
{
      man m = ppl[i] as man;

      if(m.Name.ToLower() == "nimal")
          ppl.Remove(m);
}
```